# JAX-RS Client Filter to Modify Header Before Request is Dispatched to server

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

In JAX-RS (RestEasy), I want to implement a client filter that modifies the header before sending the request so I don't do this manually for every single call.

Currently I'm doing this in the receiving end to intercept requests before arriving to the resource.

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // read header
    }
```

Now I know this (Correct me if I'm wrong):

In the receiving end, `ContainerRequestFilter` can be used before the request arrives to the resource and get the request.

But I want to implement this in the client side, to modify the header before the request is ever sent to the server. Can the same server filter be used or there is something similar to for the client?

Comment: @peeskillet yeah the filter gets called before the resource method is called at the receiver end. But I want to implement a similar filter in the sending point before the request is sent! See Luca's answer.

Comment: @peeskillet Sorry for that, I guess the last part of the question was not clear that I meant the client (sending end). Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must register a [ClientRequestFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html) into your [Client](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html)

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MyFilter.class);

@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext ctx) throws IOException {
        // modify header before send: ctx.getHeaders() 
    }
}
```